# How to prevent window.onbeforeunload event being triggered by refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on site where i need to remove all the data from the database before user leaves the website and probably i will have to work with the `window.onbeforeunload()` event i have figure out the problem with links but still i am facing one problem when i refresh the page the event `window.onbeforeunload()` trigger's and i want only to trigger this function on browser close how can i prevent this function to trigger on the browser refresh. Further the Actions that invoke the onbeforeunload event are following:

- Navigating to another page directly in the browser or via a link.
- Closing the current browser window or tab page. Reloading the current
- page. Manipulating the URL of the currently loaded page through the
- location object from JavaScript. Invoking the window.navigate method.
- Invoking the window.open or the document.open method to open a
  document in the same window.

I have figured out all the points except the third one that is Reloading the current page i want this triggers don't work on Reloading the current page .
Here is my jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(){
         window.onbeforeunload = null;
       });
    });

      var session_id="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_id');?>";
      var hook = true;
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (hook) {

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"<?=base_url();?>temp_delete",
        data:"session_id="+session_id,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#remove").html();
        }
       });
          return "Did you save your stuff?"
        }
      }

      function unhook() {
        hook=false;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: be prepared and search for "unbeforeunload crossbrowser" to not have the mess later on

Comment: Did you search? I am sure you will find plenty of results that say "You Can't"

Comment: i have been searching this topic from round about 5 hours finally i came here and ask

Comment: my first priority is chrome and is working in chrome only the problem i am facing is refreshing

Comment: and you will get the same from here dear, you can't.. and I think changing the logic should be a better way to go, other than doing such, as it truly will be a mess to maintain with different browsers/versions

Comment: yea you are right that i will have problem with cross browsers dear but i want to fit this one because according to user priority

Comment: It's simply a big big trouble (IMO) if you rely on onbeforeunload (refresh? navigate away? back/forward?) how much code you have/had to write to manage that? Is it reliable? Not really. **Shouldn't it be better if done server side?** When a "session" expires then server will clean database. When new session starts then server will (eventually) clean a previous uncleaned session. Client won't be aware of this. If you don't have load balancing it should be much much easier (and also portable, even if TODAY you don't care about this).

Comment: you mean i have to let it on server but i have current session id which generates automatically after some time and i cant figure this out without using onbeforeunload event but thanks you gave me another idea on which i can work thanks alot for your precious time and finally i get the answer that it can't be figure out ..

Comment: Not possible. There is no way to know the difference between unload happening from closing the browser, reloading the page, or changing the url in the address bar. Instead, stop using onbeforeunload for this functionality, use a timeout instead.

Comment: Yes, I thought something like that (similar to ASP.NET sessions) but any other server side solution may also work in your scenario!